# Export Highchart + HTML as Image in angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, html, canvas, highcharts, html5-canvas

We have angular js application which uses highchart js library. We have made several widget which display combination of data, let say in some widget we have only highchart, in some we have only tabular data rendered with angular directive, while in some widget we have combination of both i.e. highchart + some HTML (it can be simple bullet list or let say tabular data rendered with angular). Now we want to give functionality so that each widget can be exported as image.

We came across this example **jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/** which work well with HTML only data, but highchart is not exported with this.

We thought to generate image from server side through C#, but each widget is generated with js library (highchart & angular), so in this case we do not have any direct support on server side.

What are the solution for above scenario? or what can be other approach to achieve similar.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you came across this Highcharts [Exporting](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview) module. I'm using this so called 'plugin' in my web application to generate image for Highcharts.

Comment: yes we checked that, but our problem is that just for export functionality, we cannot install PHP or JAVA on our production server. Other than that, as I mentioned in question, we require to export widget which can be combination of highchart and/or html generated with angular, even if we setup export server, I doubt other HTML data will not exported.

Comment: Maybe the offline export is the solution for you? http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export

Comment: offline export will be helpful to export only chart, but in our case we require to export HTML element (basically DIV), which contain highchart as well some other HTML data, and this offline export solution will not work in this situation. or am I missing something?